# MAUI: How to close Communitytoolkit.Maui.Views PopUp page from Content View page

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am using the .NET Community toolkit for the Popup page. The opening and closing are working fine for the popup page from the Content page. But I am unable to close the popup page from the Content View page.

I used the Close(); to close the popup page from the Content View page, but I got an error.

Below is the error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0103 The name 'Close' does not exist in the current context

I have tried different solutions to fix this issue, but they didn't help. Can you please provide me with a solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Instead of describing what you've tried, you should be showing the code you've tried. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where do you instantiate the popup, where are you trying to call the `Close()` method?

Comment: what object are you calling `Close()` on?  Posting an error message with no accompanying code to show the context is almost completely useless.

Comment: On Android, alerts can be dismissed by [tapping on the page outside the alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0#display-an-alert). And on Windows platforms, alerts can be dismissed with the escape key. Don't you want to use these methods to close the Pop-up Page? You can add more code information about you project, which can help me understand you problem better.